# "Repository:" field in R DESCRIPTION files

Tags: r, repository, metadata, cran, packrat

**Question:** What is the purpose and origin of the `Repository:` field in a package `DESCRIPTION` file?

It doesn't seem to be mentioned in [the official docs for DESCRIPTION files](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#The-DESCRIPTION-file), nor in [Hadley's book](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/description.html).  It seems to be auto-populated during CRAN upload - e.g. it's not in [`dplyr`'s original DESCRIPTION source](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/master/DESCRIPTION), but it's present in [the CRAN tarball](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/dplyr_0.8.1.tar.gz) DESCRIPTION:

```
...
Maintainer: Hadley Wickham <hadley@rstudio.com>
Repository: CRAN
Date/Publication: 2019-05-14 12:20:03 UTC
```

**Background:** I ask because [`packrat`](https://rstudio.github.io/packrat/) seems to use the presence/absence of this field to determine whether a package can be found in a repository somewhere - if not, it requires you to download it manually.  This is a problem for locally-developed packages that are hosted in a local CRAN-like repository.

We can start adding the `Repository:` field to our local packages, but that's kind of a pain to do with all the previous versions, it will mess up their tarball checksum, etc.  And I wouldn't want to do it without understanding what it's for.

Comment: Update: I found an open `packrat` ticket from a few months ago about this: https://github.com/rstudio/packrat/issues/528

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be a field added silently by both CRAN and Bioconductor, and taken advantage of by `packrat`.  I contributed a Pull Request (now merged) to allow the field to be missing: https://github.com/rstudio/packrat/pull/569.  The GitHub issue has now been resolved: https://github.com/rstudio/packrat/issues/528.